# what does getIn() do in Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Unfortunately the documentation is very sparse :

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn

Does anyone have an example? I am *guessing* that if I have a myObject like so :

```
  a: {
    b:{
      c:"banana"
    }
  }
```

that

> myObject.getIn(["a", "b", "c"])

will return banana.

However the immutable objects can also be map objects which leaves me thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Shortly**:

`map.getIn(["a", "b", "c"])` is a shortcut to `map.get("a").get("b").get("c")`

**In details:**

You have probably got into one of the `fromJS` traps. Calling :

```
const map = Immutable.fromJS({a: {b: {c: "banana"}}});
```

creates a `Map` with only key `a`, which's value is also a `Map` with only key `b`, which's value is also a `Map` with only key `c` and value `banana`.

With other words `fromJS` goes into the deep of the object provided, and defines `Map` for each `Object` and a `List` for each `Array`

With this example, calling `map.getIn(["a", "b", "c"])` is kind of a shortcut to `map.get("a").get("b").get("c")`

But if you define `map` as a `Map`:

```
const map = new Immutable.Map({a: {b: {c: "banana"}}});
```

it creates a Map, with only key `a`, which's value is plain object `{b: {c: "banana"}}`, and calling a `map.get("a").get("b").get("c")` will throw you something like `get is not a function`, since `map.get("a")` will return `{b: ...}` plain object.

Same reasons are why `map.getIn(["a", "b", "c"])` will not work as you might expect.