# Immutable JS: updating the nested dynamic object

Tags: redux, immutable.js, redux-immutable

My initial state is,

```
export const initialState = fromJS({
  current: {},
  page: {
    loading: false,
    isFirstLoaded: false,
  },
  meta: {},
});
```

In My reducer, since I have defined the nested structure for `page`,

```
state.setIn(['page', 'loading'], true);
```

works fine.

Since I haven't defined the nested structure for `current` or `meta`

```
state.setIn(['current', 'status'], 'done')
```

throws an error **'Invalid keypath'**

When I logged the state,

```
{
   current: {..with properties including status is there as object..},
   page: Map, // <--- why this alone being as Immutable Map,
   meta: {}, // <--- This is also being as plain object
}
```

Comment: When do you do `state.setIn...`

Comment: I have answered very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515723/what-does-getin-do-in-immutable-js/43518153#43518153

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `mergeIn` method in your case as per the following documentation: http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeIn.

Hope it helps!